# Incorrect type in tree folding lambda function

Tags: haskell, lambda

I'm doing exercises with Binary Trees:

```
data BinaryTree a =
    Leaf
  | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
  deriving (Show)
```

I implemented a fold function for the tree:

```
foldTree :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTree _ start Leaf = start
foldTree f start (Node left x right) = f x (foldTree f start left) (foldTree f start right)
```

Now I tried to rewrite my old map function using fold:

```
mapTree' :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
mapTree' f bt = foldTree (\l x r -> Node l (f x) r) Leaf bt
```

However, it's telling me that `x` in the above lambda is of type BinaryTree

```
x :: BinaryTree b (bound at app/Main.hs:85:30)
```

I'm confused because if I do `:t Node` in `ghci` I get:

```
Node :: BinaryTree a -> a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
```

So in my mind `x` should be of type `a` because it's in the middle position of the `Node` constructor.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change either `foldTree` to have a shape of `BinaryTree`

```
foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
-------------^----^
foldTree _ start Leaf = start
foldTree f start (Node left x right) = f (foldTree f start left) x (foldTree f start right)
```

or fix argument order in `mapTree’`:

```
mapTree' :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
mapTree' f bt = foldTree (\x l r -> Node l (f x) r) Leaf bt
---------------------------^
```

Comment: Oh I see! So my ordering of arguments in foldTree wasn't in line with my definition of Node.